# Problem with sorting different objects from json in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I'm making a program in JavaScript to visualize different data on one chart in browser. So I use a lot of different objects from different jsons, which are concatenated in one array. So the problem is to sort them in one order.

I used a simply sort function(below), but it only works on Firefox, not on Chrome. I have installed latest version of browsers. Here are my objects and code:

```
[
{"qlevel":"OK","comment":"passed","up":"CXR18B","time_test":1557144779},

{"qlevel":"NOT OK","comment":"not passed","up":"CXR18B","time_test":1557217861},

{"num":"10","type":"Total Exception","time_test":1557327993}
]
```

```
 var data= JSON.parse(this.responseText);
 console.log(data);

 allDomain = allDomain.concat(data);

 allDomain.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.time_test - b.time_test;
    });
```

As you can see, my objects are different, but they have one common field "time_test" and I want to sort my array by "time_test" value, which is time stamp.
In the code you can see that I get new data and concatenate that data with old ones to array allDomain.

In the end I sort this by function "sort", which works on firefox, but not on chrome and I don't know why.

Thanks in advice for your help.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your sort method? That's where you should start.

Comment: Hi perhaps the error is in a different part of the code? The sort is fine.

Comment: What does it mean: 'not working'? What's the actual  result? Do you have any errors?

Comment: No, I did not. I'm new in java script, how should I do this?

Comment: Use the browser's debugger. http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820

Comment: I do not have any errors. The array is sorted only in the same objects.

Comment: You were right, the problem is not in sort function. It is asynchronous problem. Program is drawing chart before sort function ended. You have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: The only one solution is to draw your charts after ending of asyns request.